# Shortcut to switch from one "to be replaced" text to another in TexStudio

Tags: texstudio

I have a question about TexStudio which seems basic but to which I struggle to find an answer.
When I use autocompletion, for example to open a new environment, there is text which is automatically written and which I should have to replace (like *environment-name* or *content...* in the following picture).

[image: An example : here, *environment-name* and content... are "to be replaced" words]

I assume there is a shortcut to go from one of these "to be replaced" text but I did not find it.

I looked on google and this site with keywords around autocompletion and highlighting, and look at some documentation around autocompletion but I did not found anything related to these "to be replaced" words.

So, I have two questions : do you know the shortcut ? what is the official name for these "to be replaced" words ?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use `Ctrl + →` or `Ctrl + ←` to jump from one placeholder to another. Typing `Enter` cancels the placeholder.